# Inlining virtual methods and static analysis during optimisation stage

Tags: c++, optimization

I am reading the ["Optimized C++"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920038030.do) book and it is told there that the compiler is able to perform optimisations like inlining virtual methods during successful static dispatch (when the compiler was able to see that no dynamic dispatch will be required). However, this does not seem to work.

[The following code](https://godbolt.org/g/yUvm1U) illustrates a simple case when it can not be done due to some reason:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    __attribute__((always_inline))
    virtual int f(const int x) {
        if (x > 6) {
            return x * 5;
        } else {
            return x - 5;
        }
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    __attribute__((always_inline))
    int f(const int x) override {
        if (x > 10) {
            return x * 7;
        } else {
            return x - 2;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    A *a = new B;
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    return a->f(n);
}
```

This leads to a function call and virtual table generation even with `always_inline` and -O3 (however, this kind of optimisations is usually performed even at -O1 level). The question is why the compiler does so in such a very simple case, and then we even say to inline it: the compiler is able to see that there is no dynamic dispatch required because we know the exact type of a variable (it is `B`) and it does not change during the whole runtime and it can be seen from compile time.

Comment: [It will work if you change declarations to `class B final:` and `B *a = new B;`](https://godbolt.org/g/bAzvji)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc doesn't have heap elision, a practice of removing unneeded heap allocations. You can see it for yourself in [this small example](https://godbolt.org/g/FGmafp):

```
int main() {
  int *Value = new int(10);
  return *Value;
}
```

This means that in your example it can't look through `a` and optimize appropriately to remove the virtual table. Note that gcc does indeed ellide the virtual table it you [don't use heap allocations](https://godbolt.org/g/YNCevW):

```
// ...
B b;
A &a = b;
// ...
```

As a final note: clang *does* support heap elision, as can be seen [in the assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/c3PZye) without any virtual tables.